# Why is all my system text highlighted black?

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, 16.10, amd-graphics

[Image of what my system text looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmud5.jpg) I installed ubuntu 16.10 onto my Lenovo Ideapad 110 with an AMD A9 processor, and Radeon R5 Graphics card. After I installed Ubuntu and loaded it for the first time, all my system text is highlighted black making it extremely difficult to read. From Terminal to System settings. I do not know what went wrong with the install. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Make sure your system is fully updated - `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` -, reboot and try again.

Comment: Tried that to no avail. Am editing my post to include an image of what my system text looks like.

Comment: Was it like that in the live session?

Comment: It has been like that ever since the initial install about a week ago. After the initial install and first boot up I got the same system problem error message.

Comment: Also, I tried the - sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop - with no luck.